# Getting an event of the table's cell value wrapping

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table in Document and I would like to add spaces to the middle of cell value until the cell value is wrapped. The aim is to fit the cell value with added spaces to the whole cell width. If there are any other options, I'll be grateful for your sharing.

```
Sub Tablll()
 If ThisDocument.Tables.Count > 0 Then ThisDocument.Tables(1).Delete
 
ThisDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=2, _
NumColumns:=1, DEfaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed

With ThisDocument.Tables(1)
    .Rows(1).Cells(1).Range = "some text"
    ' ... some magic here ... '
End With
End Sub
```

[screenshot what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnd2O.png)

Comment: Using spaces for formatting is a terrible idea. Why not simply add a Carriage Return (CR)?     `.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range = "some text" & vbCr & "some more text"`

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off just living with whatever justified paragraph alignment gives you, but if you really want to detect that, there is no obvious event, but you could compare the vertical position of the first and last characters of the range.

You have to exclude the end of cell marker from the range, so perhaps something like

```
Dim tRange As Word.Range
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  Set tRange = .Rows(1).Cells(1).Range
  tRange.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart
  tRange.Text = "some text"
  With tRange.Characters    
    If .First.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) <> .Last.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) Then
      ' the text wrapped
    Else
      ' the text didn't wrap
    End If
  End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function IsCellWrapped(tbl As Table, x As Integer, y As Integer)
    Dim myT As Table
    Dim rngCel As Range
    Dim firstLine As Long
    Dim lastLine As Long
    Set myT = tbl
    Set rngCel = myT.cell(x, y).Range
            firstLine = rngCel.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
            rngCel.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            rngCel.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
            lastLine = rngCel.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
            IsCellWrapped = lastLine > firstLine
End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).